# How can a Wifi access point give me a location?

Tags: mobile, location, wifi, tablet

If I'm connected to a Wifi access point on a mobile device that doesn't have GPS or 3G how can a location-based service get my location? Does the access point provide a standard way of querying its lat/long or is there a database of locations of IP addresses?

I'm interested in any standards for doing this, rather than technically possible methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found of doing this is using [gpsd](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/). If the Wifi access point is running OpenWRT then you can use this article [GPS receiver in OpenWrt](http://h-wrt.com/en/doc/gps) but it should be possible to use the gpsd standard on any access point.